# SPARQL results that exists only in one of two languages

Tags: set, sparql

I have to do a SPARQL query that should output the results that have a label in English but not in Russian. The output should be just the results in English language.

I will put here the code that I was trying to do:

```
select ?m ?l where {
   ?m rdf:type dbo:Mountain;
      dbo:locatedInArea dbr:Nepal;
      dbo:elevation ?a;
      rdfs:label ?l.
FILTER ((?a >= 8000) && (langMatches(lang(?l), "en")) )

MINUS {

select ?m ?l where {
   ?m rdf:type dbo:Mountain;
      dbo:locatedInArea dbr:Nepal;
      dbo:elevation ?a;
      rdfs:label ?l.
   FILTER ((?a >= 8000) && (langMatches(lang(?l), "ru")) )}
 }
}
```

Comment: `select ?m ?l where {
   ?m rdf:type dbo:Mountain;
      dbo:locatedInArea dbr:Nepal;
      dbo:elevation ?a;
      rdfs:label ?l.
FILTER ((?a >= 8000) && (langMatches(lang(?l), "en")) )
FILTER NOT EXISTS {?m rdfs:label ?otherLabel FILTER (langMatches(lang(?otherLabel), "ru") )}
}`

Comment: I do not understand, the query returns just mountains with their English labels for which no Russian label exists. It can't return other labels than English, the filter is applied on `?l` - that's impossible. What is not working, please explain

Comment: Yes, you are right, I made a mess when I copy and paste your code. Thank you a lot, I have understood what you have done :)